# JSF <f:ajax> listener is not called after another listener was invoked from the page

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee

When I click the commandLink the listener works, and the form rerenders showing another commandLink. Then, if that command link is clicked, only the form rerenders, and listener is not called. After I refresh, everything is OK.

My JSF page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="navLink" 
            rendered="#{userBean.loggedUser ne null and not userBean.userLogged and not userBean.loggedUserFriend}">
        <h:commandLink value="Add to friends">
            <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{userBean.addToFriends}"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="navLink" rendered="#{userBean.loggedUser ne null and userBean.loggedUserFriend}">
        <h:commandLink value="Remove from friends">
            <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{userBean.removeFromFriends}"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

UserBean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean implements Serializable {

private User loggedUser;
private User user;

@EJB
private UserDAO dao;

public boolean isUserLogged() {
    return loggedUser != null && user.equals(loggedUser);
}

public boolean isLoggedUserFriend() {
    return loggedUser != null && loggedUser.getFriends().contains(user);
}

public void addToFriends() {
    if (loggedUser != null && user != null) {
        loggedUser.addFriend(user);
        dao.update(loggedUser);
    }
}

public void removeFromFriends() {
    if (loggedUser != null && user != null) {
        loggedUser.getFriends().remove(user);
        dao.update(loggedUser);
    }
}
}
```

EDIT: Also tried with a unconditionally-rendered link, to no avail

Comment: Did you miss adding AjaxBehaviorEvent to listeners or is it missing?

Comment: @johny It's missing, but adding it didn't fix anything

Comment: Two question: 1) what browser are you using? 2) do you get any client side errors (for exmple in Firebug console)?

Comment: @dratewka 1) Reproduced in Chrome 26, FF20 and IE10; 2) No errors, just POST requests.

Comment: It's a long shot but if you're using mojarra maybe try to add id's to your command links - this helped me to resolve a couple of strange ajax behaviours - don't ask why :)

Comment: @dratewka No, didn't work :)

Comment: Allright, I have found the answer, now it works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998817/jsf2-0-with-fajax-only-works-once